# Return element criteria model from attribute of a model

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel

In one of my Plugin's CP templates I am using a element select field to grab elements from a custom element type.  This field saves an array of element ids to a specific record's attribute called "location".  How do you return an element criteria model instead of the array of ids when the model attribute is called via twig?

```
// Model
protected function defineAttributes()
{
    return array_merge(parent::defineAttributes(), array(
        'location'          => Attributetype::Mixed,
        'specificLocation'  => AttributeType::String,
        'registration'      => AttributeType::Mixed,
    ));
}

// Front end template
{{ craft.pluginname.variable.location }}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "plugin's fields"? Are you referring to the plugin's settings? Or a custom fieldtype?

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff it is field associated with the plugin's custom attributes not associate with settings or a custom field type.

Comment: Sorry, I might be dense but I'm not following - there's no such thing as "plugin attributes". It might help if you shared some code.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm following you correctly, seems like you could override your Model's [`getAttribute`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/BaseModel#getAttribute-detail) method to do something like this completely untested code:

```
public function getAttribute($name, $flattenValue = false)
{
    if ($name == 'location' && $flattenValue != false)
    {
        $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria('MyPlugin_MyElementType');
        $criteria->location = parent::getAttribute($name, $flattenValue);
        return $criteria;
    }

    return parent::getAttribute($name, $flattenValue);
}
```

If I'm not following you correctly, then that was pointless.

Comment: The code is now tested and works. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome... lucky guess!